# httpd-2.4.10 fails starting with "Regex could not be compiled"

Tags: linux, apache

I have build apache httpd-2.4.10 on RHEL5 using (pcre is installed)

```
"--with-included-apr" \
"--prefix=/opt/isv/apache/httpd-2.4.10" \
"--enable-authnz-ldap" \
"--enable-ldap" \
"--enable-ssl" \
"--with-ldap" \
"--with-pcre" \
"--enable-pcre" \
exit 0
```

When I try to start with

```
./apachectl -D LCP_QA  -f /opt/isv/apache/httpd-2.4.10/conf/cg_test_httpd.conf
```

The error is

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 227 of /opt/isv/apache/httpd-2.4.10/conf/cg_test_httpd.conf:
Regex could not be compiled
```

The line throwing the error is

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

This same conf file works on the 2.4.3 build.

Comment: Just found the solution. I had to rebuild specifying the path to the downloaded pcre --with-pcre=/opt/isv/src/SOURCES/httpd-2.4.10/srclib/pcre/pcre-config

Comment: Write that as an answer to yourself and accept it. This way it will not be marked as an unanswered question, plus other people encountering the same problem may benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution. I had to rebuild specifying the path to the downloaded pcre --with-pcre=/opt/isv/src/SOURCES/httpd-2.4.10/srclib/pcre/pcre-config